# Show: $X_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{d}} X$, then $\mathbb{E}\lvert X\rvert\leqslant\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\lvert X_n\rvert$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, weak-convergence

> > Let $X_n, X$ be random variables with $X_n\xrightarrow{d} X$. Show that then
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{E}\lvert X\rvert\leqslant\liminf_n \mathbb{E}\lvert X_n\rvert.
> > $$

So let $X_n\xrightarrow{d} X$; in our lecture this means that for all bounded continious functions $f$ it is
$$
\lim_n\int f\circ X_n\, d\mathbb{P}=\int f\circ X\, d\mathbb{P}.~~~~~~~~~(*)
$$

---

I do not know, how to make the proof. Nonetheless, my first idea was, to work with Fatou's lemma, i.e.
$$
\liminf_n\mathbb{E}\lvert X_n\rvert\geqslant\mathbb{E}\liminf_n\lvert X_n\rvert=\int\liminf_n\lvert X_n\rvert\, d\mathbb{P}.
$$

Now I do not know how to continue (in case that this is the right start).

Maybe you can help me.

With greetings

math12

Answer (score 2):

Fatou's lemma is true when we have almost sure convergence but here we only have convergence in distribution. The problem can be settled in this way plus Skorohod representation but it's an overkill way.

However, we can use the definition of convergence in distribution for the map $$f_R(x):=\begin{cases}
x&\mbox{ if }-R\leqslant x\leqslant R;\\
R&\mbox{ if }x\gt R\\
-R&\mbox{ if }x\lt R.
\end{cases}$$
(that is, $f_R(x)=\min\{|x|,R\}\leqslant x$)
This function is continuous and bounded, hence for each $R$,
$\mathbb E[f_R(X_n)]\to\mathbb E[f_R(X)]$. Since $f_R(x)\leqslant |x|$ for any $x$,
$$\mathbb E[f_R(X)]=\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\mathbb E[f_R(X_n)]
\leqslant  \liminf_{n\to+\infty}\mathbb E|X_n|.$$
We conclude as $R$ was arbitrary.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to apply this function $f$ in order to show the claim.

Comment: There was a mistake in the definition. Now I think it's correct.

Comment: Do not see why $E[f_R(X)]\leqslant\liminf_n E[f_R(X_n)]\leqslant\liminf_n E[X_n]$.

Comment: The first or second inequality?

Comment: Unfortunately both, sorry.

Comment: The first one is actually an equality (see edit) and follows from the definition of convergence in distribution. The second one follows from the inequality $f_R(t)\leqslant |t|$ for each $R$.

Comment: Just two questions. First, the function $f_{R}(x)$ has a discontinuity at $x = -R$, right?. Second, the final step is to take limit when $R \to \infty$ in order to obtain $E(X)$ from $E(f_{R}(X))$?. thanks!

Comment: @DIEGOR. Thanks for pointing this out. Indeed, as $R$ goes to infinity, $E(f_{R}(X)) converges to $E(X)$.